# Rewrite image link in angular app with a different domain than native

Tags: angular, angular-router

I suppose this can be done on http server level since I am using the same domain on angular app for server and client.

But say if I want angular to fetch the image from another domain based the URL I am having in my content. How can the angular do it?

Say this image url is relative `src='/php-load-image/abc.jpg`, how can I rewrite it in angular routing level or http request level? I don't know how to put it but surely I can also parse that url and replace the relative path to another domain path.

Comment: So do you want to change the path of the image?

Comment: Yes. want to add a domain to it.